# Convert image URL in javascript

Tags: javascript, cordova

Any other way to convert image URL to base64 or blob? I want to store 900 images in sqlite database in cordova App for use it in offline mode. All images are in HD so I can't convert using canvas. Then I tried XMLHttpRequest but it takes a lots of time to convert in base64. So can anyone give you other solution to store image in database. 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try this plugin https://github.com/chrisben/imgcache.js/... download the images in device and you can get them by url...

Comment: Please mention your exact situation, caching 900 HD images(`~900MB`?) in mobile doesn't sound like a good thing, you probably have to rethink about this requirement, especially when offline databases doesn't  offer too much MBs. Even if you want to cache I would recommend using `Application Cache` instead of `webSQL`.

Comment: @sabithpocker I want to store in  around 900 images in sqlite database. every images are around 1MB. Whenever user is in offline mode user can see all images from database this is my requirement. But when I convert image in base64 it takes a lot of time. So I need other solution rather convert in base64 like in native app they convert image in bytes.

Comment: I was asking you why you are doing this? What are you developing? Can there be a different approach than caching 900 HD images? Also try if you can convert it from server and send the base64 as string to browser, create an api around this concept so that processing is moved to server. `api/base64/20/30` would return a JSON with `base64` of 20th to 30th image.PS: This indeed looks like a [XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Comment: sorry for misunderstanding. It's one project to display book pdf in Mobile App. So first backend developer convert pdf into images and then send it in api.Now I convert this images in base64 for offline use. I didn't know it's a good way or not. But It's requirement to show all images of pdf in offline.

Comment: Why can't you store/display the pdf directly ?

Comment: @Kaiido But I have to display all images in page flip. Is it possible directly in PDF? And how it works offline?

Comment: Sorry for long time off. I am not sure what you clearly means by "page flip" but you should probably be able to do it thanks to [pdf.js](https://mozilla.github.io/pdf.js/) which has an option to export every pages as images. For the offline part, the only problem you might encounter is that the pdf files should be saved in the same repertory as your viewer.html

Answer (score 1):

> Whatever you are doing try to avoid this much HD images.

Just enumerating the concepts mentioned in comments:

1. Cache images with `Application Cache` and save the `URI`s in database.
2. Convert all images to `base64` manually and store them in `JSON` in server, client can now just access these static `JSON` from server. Think of splitting them to chunks of 2-3 images/ `JSON`.
3. Create an `API` that would reply with `base64` of requested images. The `API` would fetch the image just in time, calculate the `base64` and reply with `JSON` containing the `base64` as string.

Comment: I'd highly recommend #1 and use image compression beforehand.